# Flutter packages get didnt install http package

Tags: get, flutter, package

I am new in flutter and when I used flutter packages get on the command it answered  with the 4 seconds that lasted but when I take a look at the .packages archive it didn't download all the packages. Is there any other way to download packages?
pub get did the same thing.
This is the pubspec.yaml

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
  version: 1.0.0+1

 environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

 dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter

 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    http: ^0.12.0

  dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
   sdk: flutter
```

A friend of mine did the same thing but the packages were downloaded with no problem

Comment: please paste your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Did you list `http: ...` in `dependencies:` in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: The issue is not in the pubspec. The package isnt downloading

Comment: because something could be wrong in your pubspec.yaml,  could you update your question?

Comment: Its updated with the pubspec.yaml

Comment: "The package isnt downloading" is there any related console log? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: "I take a look at the .packages archive it didn't download all the packages." what does that mean exactly? How did you derive that?

Comment: When looking at .packages I see what is on the picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Am-WRHZpIThYov_LvZFeXMNv2xQXQnY/view but there is no http package there and going to the foldiers there isnt one either, so I assume the packages get isnt working as it is supposed to